# Scrapy - How does a request sent using requests library to an API differs from the request that is sent using Scrapy.Request?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am a beginner at using Scrapy and I was trying to scrape this website https://directory.ntschools.net/#/schools which is using javascript to load the contents. So I checked the networks tab and there's an API address available https://directory.ntschools.net/api/System/GetAllSchools If you open this address, the data is in XML format. But when you check the response tab while inspecting the network tab, the data is there in json format.

I first tried using Scrapy, sent the request to the API address WITHOUT any headers and the response that it returned was in XML which was throwing JSONDecode error upon using json.loads(). So I used the header 'Accept' : 'application/json' and the response I got was in JSON. That worked well

```
import scrapy
import json
import requests

class NtseSpider_new(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ntse_new'
    header = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
         'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/107.0.1418.56',
    }
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://directory.ntschools.net/api/System/GetAllSchools',callback=self.parse,headers=self.header)



    def parse(self,response):
        data = json.loads(response.body) #returned json response
```

But then I used the requests module WITHOUT any headers and the response I got was in JSON too!

```
import requests

import json


res = requests.get('https://directory.ntschools.net/api/System/GetAllSchools')

js = json.loads(res.content) #returned json response
```

Can anyone please tell me if there's any difference between both the types of requests? Is there a default response format for requests module when making a request to an API? Surely, I am missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Scrapy sets the `Accept` header to 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml ...'. You can see that from [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.7.1/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py#L53).

I experimented and found that server sends a JSON response if the request has no `Accept` header.

Comment: Wow, thanks, very helpful! One question, I see that in the settings file of my scrapy project, this portion of 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' is commented out. So does it still get executed upon running the scraper? Is that the default setting then? I think that's the case, all the commented-out portions are actually the default settings?

Comment: The commented values are just examples for documentation. For the ```DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS```, it's identical to the default value. You can compare values in [default_settings.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.7.1/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py) and [settings.py.tmpl](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/2.7.1/scrapy/templates/project/module/settings.py.tmpl).